# Efficiently sharing data between processes in different languages

Tags: java, c#, .net, ipc

## Context

I am writing a Java program that communicates with a C# program through standard in and standard out. The C# program is started as a child process. It gets "requests" through stdin and sends "responses" through stdout. The requests are very lightweight (a few bytes size), but the responses are large. In a normal run of the program, the responses amount for about 2GB of data.

I am looking for ways to improve performance, and my measurements indicate that writing to stdout is a bottleneck. Here are the numbers from a normal run:

- Total time: 195 seconds
- Data transferred through stdout: 2026MB
- Time spent writing to stdout: 85 seconds
- stdout throughput: 23.8 MB/s

By the way, I am writing all the bytes to an in-memory buffer first, and copying them in one go to stdout to make sure I only measure stdout write time.

## Question

What is an efficient and elegant way to share data between the C# child process and the Java parent process? It is clear that stdout is not going to be enough.

I have read here and there about sharing memory through memory mapped files, but the Java and .NET APIs give me the impression that I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Maybe consider a named pipe, or (probably fastest you could get, but more fiddly to orchestrate) a memory mapped file. There are libraries to access both of those for Java (and obviously C# too).

Comment: you could just save the response content as a file or cache, and then just include a pointer to this content in your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matthew Watson mentioned in the comments, it is indeed possible and incredibly fast to use a memory mapped file. In fact, the throughput for my program went from 24 MB/s to 180 MB/s. Below is the gist of it.

The following Java code creates the memory mapped file used for communication and opens a buffer we can read from:

```java
var path = Paths.get("test.mmap");
var channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
var mappedByteBuffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 200_000 * 8);
```

The following C# code opens the memory mapped file and creates a stream that you can use to write bytes to it (note that `buffer` is the name of the array of bytes to be written):

```cs
// This code assumes the file has already been created on the Java side
var file = File.Open("test.mmap", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
var memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(file, fileName, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, HandleInheritability.None, false);
var stream = memoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream();
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stream.Flush();
```

Of course, you need to somehow synchronize the Java and the C# side. For the sake of simplicity, I didn't include that in the code above. In my code, I am using standard in and standard out to signal when it is safe to read / write.

Answer (score 1):

Before you invest more in memory mapped files or named pipes I would first check whether you actually read and write efficiently. `java.lang.Process.getInputStream()` uses a BufferedInputStream, so the reader side should be OK. But in your C# program you will most likely use `Console.Write`. The problem here is that AutoFlush is enabled by default. So every single write explicitely flushes the stream. I wrote my last C# code years ago, so I'm not up-to-date. But maybe it is possible to set the AutoFlush property of Console.Out to false and flush the stream manually after multiple writes.

If disabling AutoFlush should not be possible the only way to improve performance with Console.Out would be to write more text with a single write.

Another potential bottleneck may be a shell in between that has to interpret the written data. Ensure that you execute the C# program directly and not through a script or by calling the command executor.

Before you start using memory mapped files I would first try to simply write into a file. As long as you have enough free memory that is not used by your programs or others and as long as there are no other programs with frequent disk access the operating system will be able to hold quite a big amount of written data within the file system cache. As long as your Java program reads fast enough from file while your C# program is writing to the file chances are high that only some or even no data has to be loaded from disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm writing to stdout directly through bytes (sorry, just updated the question to make it clearer) so that is all right. I'll try the approach of files and see how that goes.